# How to connect to external database for PhoneGap

Tags: php, android, mysql, cordova

I am using a simple log in page as a start page to my application. When details entered, the app will check details with an external mySQL database and come back to connect or give error message. I am doing all these via php and all files are with .php extension.

But how do I do this with PhoneGap? I read around and php is not recognized on PhoneGap and moreover I can no longer place my php files on the server side. All files are going to be compiled via phonegap build which would sit on the mobile device itself.

How do I connect to my external mySQL database for PhoneGap? Seen the following guide which does uses a php script. I tried and it is not working. I don't get how it would work anyway since I can't place my php script on a server side.

[Guide](http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/)

Comment: If you can't place your PHP scripts on a server, you shouldn't be using PHP.

Comment: @Berriel So whats the alternative to connect to the database in this instance if php is not to be used?

Comment: I'm not a PhoneGap expert, but as it relies on JS+HTML, I don't think you can connect directly to a database. You'll need a server to make an interface (webservice, a simple php script, something...) with your database.

Comment: The example in the Guide link you provided shows the PhoneGap app using jQuery to post to a PHP script on the server, and then the PHP script is writing to the database. You will need to use some sort of server-based scripting language (PHP, ASP.NET, ColdFusion, etc.) on the server to interface with the database, just like he's showing you in the example.

Comment: you need to research more. This is an [FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/) SEE last question --- then GOOGLE: [phonegap connect to external](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+connect+to+external)